# Using data from d3.js outside

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm very much impressed with the data binding capabilities of d3. In an application, I need data from d3 to be used in outside functions.

For example, if data is: `[33,54,14,45,322,653,11]`. And then we do the:

```
svg.select("selection_element").data(data).enter()....
```

Now instead of entering as above, i want to use this array of data coming from d2 somewhere else. I can do it by looping through data but want to use domain, range and axis methods of D3. Is it possible that I create an array of data array from D3 and push every incoming data to this new array in `enter()` method. Unable to figure out anything.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you want to precompute the data join elsewhere?

Comment: thanks @Oleg , specifically, I want to use data from D3 in Snap.svg.js . I can get series of x and y points from D3, and then using this in snap (after some processing to this data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. You can define your scales and axes in D3 as normal, then map the input array to a new array of objects by calling your D3 methods. You can then easily pass this data to Snap.svg.

```
var input = [33, 54, 14, 45, 322, 653, 11];

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(input)
    .rangeBands([0, 550]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 800])
    .range([275, 0]);

var output = input.map(function(value){
    return {
        x: xScale(value),
        y: yScale(value)
    };
});

var svg = Snap("svg");

output.forEach(function(value){
    var c = svg.circle(value.x, value.y, 5);
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/jacomu/6/edit?html,js,output) is a JSBin demonstrating this functionality.